# Remote desktop solution working with Ubuntu 12.04 + Unity (3D)?

Tags: unity, remote-desktop, vnc, rdp, freenx

I'm trying to install a remote desktop solution on some clients using Ubuntu with Unity (3D). I've uninstalled Unity2d because it behaves not very well.

Xrdp won't work, only the wallpaper is shown.

The same goes for freenx-server.

The only servers that seems to work properly are the vnc-based as vino. Right, VNC is okay, but it is a bit slow.

Also, vino is not enough. Clients can only connect if they have manually configured the vino server, and they can't connect if the session is closed.

Sure, I could install a VNC server that launched a daemon at startup, but I want the clients to login with their credentials, and, for example, tightvncserver, only gets a global password as far as i know. Perhaps it's possible to open lightdm from a tightvncserver session?

There are two possible scenarios:

- A session is started and the client should attach to the current session.
- A session is not started, and the client should start a new one. Better if the client can logout and reattach to that session later, locally or remotely.

Comment: Just to make things clear: You want to access your ubuntu system via RDP?

Comment: RDP or NX would be great, but VNC would make it also. Whatever it is, it must cover both scenarios (login to current session and login to a new session). Thanks!

Comment: @guntbert It could be necessary. Some places still have Windows...

Comment: @icedwater, yes of course, what's your point?

Comment: I haven't found a solution to remote to Ubuntu Unity. The best I could do is xRDP with XFCE.

Answer (score 1):

I am using x2go (http://www.x2go.org/) which is based on nxclient. It does exactly what you are looking for. Just a side note: you must configure the shell to be gnome-classic instead of Unity 3d. The users will be able to log in with their credentials and also have multi-monitor support if they need it.

Comment: Thanks, but I want the solution to work with Unity 3D. Nxclient won't do that.